# replacing missing values by group conditional on date/time

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to group by `person` and `date1` and fill in missing data for `date2` and `indicator` by person and day ***IF*** with the person's next observation occurs in the same day.

For instance, `person` 1 is missing `date2` and `indicator` values for the second and third observations. As shown below, I want to replace these missing values with the next non-`NA` observation in the *same day* for this person: `date2==2018-02-02 15:04:00` and `indicator==1`.

Note that for `person` 2, the last `NA` does not have a next observation in the same day, so it needs to remain `NA`.

Here is the data frame I have:

```
  person               date1               date2 indicator
1      1 2018-02-02 12:00:00 2018-02-02 12:05:00         1
2      1 2018-02-02 13:00:00                <NA>        NA
3      1 2018-02-02 14:00:00                <NA>        NA
4      1 2018-02-02 15:00:00 2018-02-02 15:04:00         1
5      2 2018-02-01 12:00:00                <NA>        NA
6      2 2018-02-01 13:00:00 2018-02-01 13:06:00         1
7      2 2018-02-02 12:00:00 2018-02-02 12:03:00         1
8      2 2018-02-03 12:00:00                <NA>        NA
```

Here is the data frame I want:

```
  person               date1               date2 indicator
1      1 2018-02-02 12:00:00 2018-02-02 12:05:00         1
2      1 2018-02-02 13:00:00 2018-02-02 15:04:00         1
3      1 2018-02-02 14:00:00 2018-02-02 15:04:00         1
4      1 2018-02-02 15:00:00 2018-02-02 15:04:00         1
5      2 2018-02-01 12:00:00 2018-02-01 13:06:00         1
6      2 2018-02-01 13:00:00 2018-02-01 13:06:00         1
7      2 2018-02-02 12:00:00 2018-02-02 12:03:00         1
8      2 2018-02-03 12:00:00                <NA>        NA
```

Example:

```
library(tidyverse)
df.have <- data.frame(person=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                      date1=ymd_hms(c("2018-02-02 12:00:00", 
                                      "2018-02-02 13:00:00", 
                                      "2018-02-02 14:00:00", 
                                      "2018-02-02 15:00:00",
                                      "2018-02-01 12:00:00", 
                                      "2018-02-01 13:00:00", 
                                      "2018-02-02 12:00:00", 
                                      "2018-02-03 12:00:00")),
                       date2=ymd_hms(c("2018-02-02 12:05:00", 
                                       NA, 
                                       NA, 
                                       "2018-02-02 15:04:00",
                                       NA, 
                                       "2018-02-01 13:06:00", 
                                       "2018-02-02 12:03:00", 
                                       NA)),
                       indicator=c(1, NA, NA, 1,
                                   NA, 1, 1, NA))

df.want <- data.frame(person=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                      date1=ymd_hms(c("2018-02-02 12:00:00", 
                                      "2018-02-02 13:00:00", 
                                      "2018-02-02 14:00:00", 
                                      "2018-02-02 15:00:00",
                                      "2018-02-01 12:00:00", 
                                      "2018-02-01 13:00:00", 
                                      "2018-02-02 12:00:00", 
                                      "2018-02-03 12:00:00")),
                      date2=ymd_hms(c("2018-02-02 12:05:00", 
                                      "2018-02-02 15:04:00",
                                      "2018-02-02 15:04:00", 
                                      "2018-02-02 15:04:00",
                                      "2018-02-01 13:06:00", 
                                      "2018-02-01 13:06:00", 
                                      "2018-02-02 12:03:00", 
                                      NA)),
                      indicator=c(1, 1, 1, 1,
                                  1, 1, 1, NA))
```

I can filter down to some of the replacement values, but still a good bit from where I want to get.

```
df.have %>%
  group_by(person, date(date1)) %>%
  arrange(person, date1) %>%
  filter(row_number() %in% c(n()))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this (note that you also need `lubridate` as well as the `tidyverse` packages)...

```
df.want <- df.have %>% mutate(day=date(date1)) %>% #add a date variable for grouping
                       group_by(day,person) %>% 
                       fill(date2,indicator,.direction = "up") %>% #use tidyr 'fill' to remove NAs
                       ungroup() %>% 
                       select(-day) %>% #remove grouping variable
                       arrange(person,date1) #restore original order

df.want

# A tibble: 8 x 4
  person               date1               date2 indicator
   <dbl>              <dttm>              <dttm>     <dbl>
1      1 2018-02-02 12:00:00 2018-02-02 12:05:00         1
2      1 2018-02-02 13:00:00 2018-02-02 15:04:00         1
3      1 2018-02-02 14:00:00 2018-02-02 15:04:00         1
4      1 2018-02-02 15:00:00 2018-02-02 15:04:00         1
5      2 2018-02-01 12:00:00 2018-02-01 13:06:00         1
6      2 2018-02-01 13:00:00 2018-02-01 13:06:00         1
7      2 2018-02-02 12:00:00 2018-02-02 12:03:00         1
8      2 2018-02-03 12:00:00                  NA        NA
```

Comment: that's really slick. `fill` `up` could not be more straightforward.